# How to build dropdown list from future in flutter

Tags: flutter, future

i want to build Dropdown list from Future,here is my function for simple list view which is working,,but how to populate drop down list from it, i am really confuse about this list map etc in flutter coming from php background,

```
 child: FutureBuilder(
    future:userApi.getUsers(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
      if(snapshot.data == null){
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Loading...")
          )
        );
      } else {
        return Container(
          child: DropdownButton(
         items: snapshot.data.map((item) {
         return DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(item.title));
         }).toList(),
         onChanged: (value){},
        )
        );
      }
    },
  ),


class UserApi{
 Future<List<User>>getUsers() async {

    var data = await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<User> users = [];

    for(var u in jsonData){

      User user = User(u["id"], u["title"]);

      users.add(user);

    }

    return users;

  }

class User {
  final int id;
  final String title;
User(this.id,this.title);

}
```

Comment: Well i found the issue but not sure about how implement it,,my future getuser() return data and it;s async function  ,so how to convert it to list again

Comment: can you have a look in the code please i have added my future function code as well ,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I just read the comment left above if your problem is getting your data then this might not help you but if snapshot has data this will work

```
//initialize this outside your build method
String dropDownValue;


 FutureBuilder(
        future:userApi.getUsers(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? Container(
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    hint: Text(dropDownValue ?? 'Make a selection'),
                    items: snapshot.data.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: item.title,
                        child: Text(item.title),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropDownValue = value;
                        print(value);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Loading...'),
                  ),
                );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: getting this error Dear type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>'

Comment: Dear the issue is if i not run builder(_,index), then i m not getting the snapshot data and i f i run that then my dropdown works but it looping the same dropdown to the length of snapshot,,,so how to avoid that can you have a look on my code above please i have added all that three function

Comment: inside this builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)  i dont want to run other loop i just want to pass the sanpshot data to the dropdown items and if i not run loop i m not getting the data however i get snapshot.data.length

Comment: well im willing to continue to still help you get this working if you want

Comment: Hello Dear sorry to disturb you again !for some reason i have used this package for dropdown https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_formfield#-example-tab-  so now how to feild that data sources values from snapshot

Answer (score 1):

you can call the map function on any list converting the elements of the list.

```
return DropdownButton(
          items: snapshot.data.map((item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(item.title));
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value){},
        );
```

if you can see here we're converting the list snapshot.data to another list of DropdownMenuItem type by calling map on snapshot.data the map function takes another function that's being called on every element of snapshot.data , map returns an Iterable of type DropdownMenuItem (the returned type of the function being called on every element) and we convert the Iterable to a list by calling toList() on it

I wish that is explanatory enough, the map function is very useful.

Comment: I i have updated the code with your example above please have a look Dear it show me this error now type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>'

Comment: @AttaullahKhan try replacing map with map<DropdownMenuItem>